# Is it possible to group results by a key with Elasticsearch aggregations?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform an Elasticsearch query and would like for Elasticsearch to group the results for me, instead of having my client code do it manually. Looking at the Elasticsearch [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html), it appears like bucketing aggregation would be what I'm looking for, but I can't find any examples that use it, or what the output would look like to be sure that's what I want.

My question is: is it possible to group documents by a key in Elasticsearch? If so, how and where can I find documentation on how to do it, either using the query DSL or (preferably) the Javadoc for the Java API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are trying to group by a field in elasticsearch, you can do it by using [Terms aggregation.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Here is how to do using query dsl,

```
POST _search 
{
   "aggs": {
      "genders": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "gender"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "top_tag_hits": {
               "top_hits": {
                  "_source": {
                     "include": [
                        "include_fields_name"
                     ]
                  },
                  "size": 100
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and **gender** is field in document, 
Its response can be

```
{
    ...

    "aggregations" : {
        "genders" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "male",
                    "doc_count" : 10,
                    "tag_top_hits":{"hits":...}
                },
                {
                    "key" : "female",
                    "doc_count" : 10,
                    "tag_top_hits":{"hits":...}
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Using [Java api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/), I've added [tophits aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) for your comment. (but not in query dsl)

```
client.prepareSearch("index").setTypes("types").addAggregation(
                AggregationBuilders.terms("agg_name").field("gender").subAggregation(
                        AggregationBuilders.topHits("documents").setSize(10)
                )
        ).execute(new ActionListener<SearchResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(SearchResponse response) {
                Terms agg_name_aggregation=response.getAggregations().get("agg_name");
                for (Terms.Bucket bucket : agg_name_aggregation.getBuckets()) {
                    TopHits topHits=bucket.getAggregations().get("documents");
                    System.out.println("term = " + bucket.getKey());
                    // do what you want with top hits..
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but that just gives me a count of the matching documents, not the documents themselves, which is what I need.

Comment: So you want documents with males and females (with reference to my example) differently? ?

Comment: I'm looking for something like key: male, docs: [list of raw documents where gender is "male"]

Answer (score 0):

**Grouping With Aggregation Function**

```
    client.prepareSearch(indexName).setTypes(documentType).addAggregation
    (AggregationBuilders.terms("agg_name").field("gender").subAggregation(
    AggregationBuilders.topHits("documents").setSize(10))).execute(new ActionListener<SearchResponse>()
    {
        public void onResponse(SearchResponse response)
        {

            Terms agg_name_aggregation=response.getAggregations().get("agg_name");


            for (Terms.Bucket bucket : agg_name_aggregation.getBuckets())
            {
                TopHits topHits=bucket.getAggregations().get("documents");

                SearchResponse response1 = client
                        .prepareSearch(indexName)

                        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("gender",bucket.getKey()))
                        .addAggregation(
                                AggregationBuilders.max("salary").field(
                                        "salary")).execute().actionGet();

                for (Aggregation avgAggs : response1.getAggregations())
                {
                    Max avg = (Max) avgAggs;

                    double maxValue = avg.getValue();

                    System.out.println("Avg Value => " + maxValue);
                }


             //   System.out.println("term = " + bucket.getKey());

             //   System.out.println("count =" + bucket.getDocCount());

              //  System.out.println(topHits.getHits());


                for (SearchHit hit: topHits.getHits())
                {

                    System.out.println(hit.getSource());
                }

            }

        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```